# dictionary is not updating in wcf service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dictionary, servicebehavior

So, I have a very simple WCF client-server app. The thing is, the service gets messages from the client and it also receives pending messages requests. However, it does not return a message to client. Instead it shows this part:
**Pending messages does not contain key {id}** although the id is fine

```
private Dictionary<int, List<Message>> pendingMessages =
    new Dictionary<int, List<Message>>();

public IEnumerable<Message> GetMessages(int id)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"New request from {id}");
    List<Message> messages;

    if (!pendingMessages.ContainsKey(id))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Pending messages does not contain key {id} ");
        return null;
    }

    messages = pendingMessages[id].ToList();
    pendingMessages[id].Clear();

    foreach (var msg in messages)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Returned message: ${msg.From}=>{msg.To}:{msg.Body}");
    }

    return messages;
}

public void SendMessage(Message msg)
{
    if (!pendingMessages.ContainsKey(msg.To))
    {
        pendingMessages.Add(msg.To,new List<Message>());
    }

    pendingMessages[msg.To].Add(msg);
    Console.WriteLine($"{msg.From}=>{msg.To}: {msg.Body}");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the instance receiving the "SendMessage" request is different from the instance receiving the "GetMessages" request? Put it this way: I'd be *astonished* if this turned out to be a bug in Dictionary. (Having said that, you appear to be using it without any sort of synchronization, and requests could come in on any thread... consider ConcurrentDictionary, or adding locking.)

Comment: How is pendingMessages defined?

Comment: Where/how is `pendingMessages` defined?

Comment: private Dictionary<int, List<Message>> pendingMessages = new Dictionary<int, List<Message>>(); that's the definition. I tried to use ConcurrentDictionary and ConcurrentBag instead of Dictionary and List but I simplified it just to find out where the error is

Comment: Every time the service is called the dictionary will be re instantiated so will be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the instance which process `GetMessages` differs from the instance which process `SendMessage` and you store your messages in local variable in your service object so different instance of the service class have different `pendingMessages`.

If you really want to make all calls to a single instance of your service you should change your service behavior. just add this attribute to your service

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

After that just one instance of your service is used for all incoming calls.

If you want to know more read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode(v=vs.110).aspx).